# How to marked as "new" to newest items in the recycler view in anroid?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, logic

I have items to show in android app via recycler view. I have successfully implemented and fetch the data from server. Items are showing in the recycler view list. I have also sorted the newest  items in the top of the list. I have done in the backend to sort the newest items in the top of the list by using php code and SQL and successfully done it. But now I want to implement a text that is this:- **NEW** in the list. Which means it will only show for the newest items and automatically deleted after 5 days.

I have successfully implement the NEW tag in the frontend and it is showing, But The new tag is only showing for the current date.
I want to show that "NEW" tag for 5 more days. I put logic but it is not helping me, and it is showing for only for the current date. Here is my code for showing NEW:-

MyAdapter class --> `onBindViewHolder()`

```
Json data:-
"creation_date": "2021-09-06"

final String creation_date = ModelClass.getCreation_date(); //JSON data "creation date". getCreation_date() invoking Getter method from model class"

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

String Current_date = sdf.format(c.getTime());

c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5); //here I have increase the date to 5
String EndDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());


 if (Current_date.equals(creation_date)) {
                        myViewHolder.creation_date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                     else if (creation_date.equals(EndDate)) {
                        myViewHolder.creation_date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        myViewHolder.creation_date.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
```

The main problem is **How can I show the NEW tag after the creation date for 5 more days and after 5 days Textview(creation_date) Visibility will be GONE?**

right now if my creation date is same with the current date then it is showing the new tag, but I want to show for 5 more days and after 5 days it should deleted.

Right now the Output is showing like this:-

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: The backend usually consists of three parts: a server, an application, and a database. So in my case it is a DATABASE or you can say a SERVER. @javdromero

Comment: Some details to add: Does each item data currently have a date/time associated with it that is accessible to the recycler view implementation?  Are you able to update the item layout or are you limited to a single line of text per item?  Do you need help with date-time arithmetic?

Comment: If it is a date-time arithmetic then yes I need help on that. Right now I don't have any idea how to implement this feature. Remember when we open any e-commerce app or something like that, we see "new" tag that is highlighted on the product,  that one I want to achieve. @Andy

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the object for "NEW" keyword in your backend while you are creating new items. Then check it on frontend side in java or whatever you are using.
You will have the item layout for your adapter in which data are being populated, so there will be a layout for "NEW" items as well which is invisible for normal items. So when you find the keyword "NEW", you can show that layout showing "NEW" keyword which was invisible till now.

That's for frontend side.

Now comes your delete logic.

If you want to delete items after 5 days, then put that time duration in the items which you want to get deleted after 5 days time. Validate items when user opens your app next time, If the time you have given is laready gone, then delete that item from the arraylist or you can delete it from the server if you have delete API.

Tell me if you have any confusion, otherwise it's good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I don't want to put manually NEW keyword in the backend. Instead of that I have created a field called "Creation date" and I called this field by using Getter method and then compare with the current system date. It is showing NEW tag but now I want to show for more 5 days and after 5 days it will invisible.

Comment: Have you tried saving data in `sqlite`?  You can compare two datasets - one from server & one from database, if server displays new data which is not yet saved in sqlite as well as if it doesn't satisfies your creation date condition, then you can display them as NEW. let me know your thoughts on it.

Comment: Alright Let me try with the sqlite. But is there any other way? I mean what if I create a field called expiration date in backend SQL and fetch as a JSON, and then give condition from creation date to expiration date...? and then it will display the TextView within the dates and after expiration the visibility GONE...

Comment: Ok. See. If you want to display the same new products for all users, then you can go that way. I thought it was different new items for different users. Yes then, you can go with that solution if all users are getting same NEW items.

Comment: Thank you.. And yes I want to show same new products for all users, since I didn't put any login or signup features... I have One more question I think You can help me, How to put logic in JAVA, If I got data only for creation date..? meaning creation date will be 06-09-2021 (dd-MM-yyyy). and expiration date will be calculated from the creation date... Can you tell me how to do that..?

Comment: I have increase the date but it does not help me, as shown in the above code... Where I have used `c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5)`

Comment: Make calendar object from creation date, then add 5 days into that object like you have typed in your comment. Then you can set alarm for that time (with 5 days added). It will trigger alarm after 5 days, then you can put your logic there in of your app's BroadcastReceiver to do wahtever you want when the alarm trigger.